# Block individual date in pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, pickadate

When I tried to block an array of individual dates, it's not blocking but when I try using some date range I am able to block the dates.

Below mentioned code is working as I am passing:

```
blocked_dates.push({ from: [2020, 4-1, 17], to: [2020, 5-1, 17], inverted: true });
```

```
@foreach($available_dates_arr as $adate)
   available_dates.push({from:new Date({{ date("Y", strtotime($adate['start'])) }}, {{ date("n", strtotime($adate['start'])) }}-1, {{ date("j", strtotime($adate['start'])) }}), to:new Date({{ date("Y", strtotime($adate['end'])) }}, {{ date("n", strtotime($adate['end'])) }}-1, {{ date("j", strtotime($adate['end'])) }})});
@endforeach

blocked_dates.push({ from: [2020, 4-1, 17], to: [2020, 5-1, 17], inverted: true });
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        disable: available_dates,
        min: min_date,
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: true,
        format: 'dd-mmm-yy'
    });
    picker = $input.pickadate('picker');

    if (blocked_dates && blocked_dates.length) {  
        picker.set('enable', blocked_dates);
    }
```

But when I pass `blocked_dates.push([2020, 4-1, 17, 'inverted']);` its not blocking the dates.

Ref : [pickadate.js](https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-enable-disable-in-range)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `blocked_dates.push([2020, 4-1, 17], 'inverted'});` would be a syntax error to begin with. And all the examples I see in that referred documentation, that use this array syntax, pass the `inverted` string _inside_ the array - `[year, month, date, 'inverted']`

Comment: @04FS While copying here i enter wrong code but i am actually passing `blocked_dates.push([2020, 4-1, 17, 'inverted']);` only.

Comment: Ended up with `blocked_dates.push({ from: [2020, 4-1, 17], to: [2020, 4-1, 17], inverted: true });`. where from and to both are same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot i came up with idea and did the same way, what i did for any date range.

So if i have to block any individual date, then i am passing the same date to both **from** and **to**.

```
blocked_dates.push({ from: [2020, 4-1, 17], to: [2020, 4-1, 17], inverted: true });
blocked_dates.push({ from: [2020, 5-1, 20], to: [2020, 5-1, 20], inverted: true });
```

I know its not the way to block individual date what they mentioned in documents but it works for me.